# Zeit Now Serverless Routing via Http Method

Tags: node.js, serverless, vercel

Using Zeit Now Serverless and Node Js, is there an out of the box way to route incoming request via path and http method?

For instance, I want requests to `GET api/cookies` to go to `getCookie()` and requests to `POST api/cookies` to go to `createCookie()`.

Comment: I made a library for my own use, but if there is something more 1st party I would like to use it.
https://github.com/Chandler-Davidson/NowRouter

Answer (score 0):

With the "rewrites" configuration this feature will be launched. For now, you can use:

```
"routes": [
  {"src": "/api/get", "dest": "api/get.js", "methods": ["GET"] },
  {"src": "/api/post", "dest": "api/post.js", "methods": ["POST"] },
]
```